# Outlook message to pop up before mail is sent in grails

Tags: email, grails

I have created an application wherein on click of a button an email with attachment is sent. The attributes for this email is hardcoded in the service method as below in my service class.

```
mailService.sendMail {  
            to   "a@xyz.com"
            from "a@xyz.com"
            cc "a@xyz.com"
            bcc "a@xyz.com"
            subject "Trading System Test Mail"
            body 'Test Mail.'
                 attach 'temp/test.pdf'
```

}

I am to enhance this application so that on click of a button, an outlook message box pops up wherein the user can edit the subject line, body,cc, bcc etc before it can be sent.

Thoughts?Sample Code??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail-Plugin of Grails is working on serverside. So there is no possibility to open a client side outlook message window. 
So what you need is to handle this on client side but that will cause a problem with the attachments.

There is no ready to use library, plugin or something you can use to do so.

Comment: Thanks Timo. In that case, what options are available. I mean, if I do not use the mail Plugin, is there any sample code available that could be used for this purpose

Comment: Alex - This can only handled with JavaScript on client side. Please take a look here for more infos: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776672/opening-outlook-through-javascript

Comment: Thanks Timo. I tried this and it works. However, one question I have here is that when u use Javascript for the mail fucntionality, u cannot specify the "from" attribute. By default the mail is sent from your id. But, this is not the case in grails. In Grails mail plugin, you can specify the "from" attribute. Am I missing something here. Is there a way to specify the "from" attribute using javascriot too???

Comment: Alex - If you open an outlook window the From field is always the user of the current PC. There i s no chance to change the from with Javascript. You can change the from only if using a serverside solution (for example the mail-plugin), but there you can not open a outlook message window. So you have to decide...

Comment: Thanks so much Timo. Your quick responses really helped me solve my issues.

Answer (score 1):

One more link that explains the Javascript handling of this issue:

http://www.outlookcode.com/d/code/formonweb.htm