# Save Generated File to local disc while using export funcitonality in Grails

Tags: javascript, email, grails, export-to-excel

Requirement:
I have a page wherein tabular data is displayed. On click of a button, this data should be exported to an excel, attached to a mail and sent.

What I have done till now:
I have achieved export to excel functionality in Grails using the export plugin.

And Mail Functionality using outlook Object in javascript as in below post.
[Outlook message to pop up before mail is sent in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130543/outlook-message-to-pop-up-before-mail-is-sent-in-grails)

However when I use OutlookObject I mention the attachment as below.

```
var attach1 = "c:\\temps\\test.txt"
```

In this case the attachment is taken from the local drive.

Question:
While I export my tabular data to an excel, Is there a way to save the file to the local drive so that the attachment can be read from the same location and sent in the mail as an attachment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't tell a browser where to save something or ask it for the location of a recently saved file so not really. What you could do is have the file exported and saved both to the users hard drive and somewhere online and use the online version when sending the email.

Comment: You mean save it in some shared drive........Could you help me with a sample code for that. That would work perfectly

Comment: not a shared drive. somewhere on your own server. The email would have to send it as a link to the file instead of an attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps here but generally there is no way to access the local file system in JavaScript.

Comment: I hava a mail functionality working using javascript wherein the attachment is taken from the local drive. Let me know if I am not making sense.      http://www.outlookcode.com/d/code/formonweb.htm

Comment: A note on that page says "[...]under the more restrictive security in Outlook 2002 and later versions, you may not be able to script Outlook from a web page [...]". It will only work on IE and old versions of outlook. Giving Javascript (as the most used web-script-language) a generic way to access the filesystem would be a horrific security issue. Almost everyone would have access to your PC. Perhaps there is a way for you without saving the file to the clients filesystem.