# chrome command for creating outlook.application object

Tags: javascript, browser, outlook, activex

Writing a script to automatically create an appointment in outlook via javascript. It works in IE but chrome doesn't use activeXObjects. Whats the code to generate the equivalent object for other browsers (IE7, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari)

```
out = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application"); //code for IE

out = ???? //Code for other browsers
```

Also, is there some outlook api for javascript?
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't expose any client application behaviors such as ActiveX does within IE. See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776672/opening-outlook-through-javascript). Outlook automation in JavaScript is only supported in IE since Microsoft has provided the necessary sandboxing for security and operating system hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code on your onclick function to open Outlook in Chrome/IE/FireFox

```
window.location.href = "mailto:?";
```