# Open outlook with javascript for sending mail with attachment in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, email

i am using javascript for open default mail client in asp.net c# web application.
below is my code..

```
<script language="javascript">
function SendAttach() {
    var theApp  //Reference to Outlook.Application 
    var theMailItem //Outlook.mailItem
    //Attach Files to the email
    var attach3 = "c:\\mail\\test.txt"
    //Construct the Email including To(address),subject,body
    //var recipient
    var subject = "Email Using JavaScript"
    var msg = "This is a test mail,sent to you using javascript by kushan thakershy"
    //Create a object of Outlook.Application
    try {
        var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
        var objNS = theApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
        var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(0) // value 0 = MailItem
        //Bind the variables with the email
        theMailItem.to = "anita.bharadva@compulynx.org"
        theMailItem.Subject = (subject);
        theMailItem.Body = (msg);
        theMailItem.Attachments.add(attach3);
        theMailItem.display();

        //Show the mail before sending for review purpose
        //You can directly use the theMailItem.send() function
        //if you do not want to show the message.

    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("The following may have cause this error: \n" +
 "1. The Outlook express 2003 is not installed on the machine.\n" +
 "2. The msoutl.olb is not availabe at the location " +
 "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\OFFICE11\\msoutl.old on client's machine " +
 "due to bad installation of the office 2003." +
 "Re-Install office2003 with default settings.\n" +
 "3. The Initialize and Scripts ActiveX controls not marked as safe is not set to enable.")
        document.write("<a href=\"" + "./testemail.asp" + "\"" + ">" + "Go Back" + "</a>")
    }

}
```

this is working fine but in my case i want to get attachment file path from server side code because i want to send crystal report as attachment.
how will i get that path from server side??

Comment: possible duplicate of [opening Outlook through javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776672/opening-outlook-through-javascript)

Comment: @DonalFellows Despite its title, the other question is ActiveX

Comment: Please specify "ServerSide Report" in more details.... you mean Crystal report .rpt file or want to attach a generated report from crystal report(in desired format .doc / .xls / .pdf)?

Answer (score 0):

check the link [opening Outlook through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776672/opening-outlook-through-javascript) OR/And [This one](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=134873)
You can try this part of code

```
function sendMail(){

location.href = "mailto:manish@simplygraphix.com?subject=Feedback for 
webdevelopersnotes.com&body=The Tips and Tricks section is 
great";




}
```