# Open Outlook "new mail" dialog and insert an attachment from an ASP.NET web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook

I was wondering if it's possible to open an Outlook 'new mail' dialog and
insert an attachment from an ASP.Net web page.

I'm trying to run this from the Intranet and the I do have outlook on my
desktop machine, which is where I am opening the page from, as would other
folks here.

I would appreciate any idea, help, tutorial.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can do that using some ActiveX object in IE, but with regular JS/HTML you can't do such things. The only way to open outlook window from browser is `<a href="mailto:...."` which will open default mail program (it may be a program different from outlook). But that is very limited option (limited size of body, no html, no attachments etc.)

Suppose the best way here will be sending email from server. You can ask user for email body and receivers list and send it usin `System.Net.Mail` namespace.

Comment: I have tried that option, but as the company has a strict firewall policies, that gave me the error : An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 172.24.105.121:25 . Any idea ?

Comment: That;s why I had the idea to add the attachment to Outlook and then send, which is allowed by firewall.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776672/opening-outlook-through-javascript) question. Maybe that will help you. But that will work in IE only. At the same time you may need some additional ActiveX to save a file on PC from web without user doing it.

Comment: But if you have different browsers to deal with - suppose the only option will be ask them to update firewall policies. At least that is the simplest solution.