# Screenshot and outlook email attachment - Javascript implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, outlook

I would like to implement a button that takes screenshot of a graph on the UI and attach that screenshot to an outlook email. With this the user is able to send that attachment to other users instantly.

This have to be done on single button click.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: maybe you could start by opening outlook from javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776672/opening-outlook-through-javascript

Comment: Well, I definitely did my research on the following. I am just concerned about the security issues as mentioned by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776672/opening-outlook-through-javascript
. I would like to know if there is a better solution and also on taking a screenshot of a graph element on UI. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to use Outlook? Where do you run a JavaScript code?

Comment: Why do you need to use Outlook? 
Corporate firms atleast 90% of them use windows as their operating system with Microsoft outlook being installed. This is currently the requirement too.
**Where do you run a Javascript code?**
I did not get this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you have in classic javascript is the `mailto` protocol. Unfortunately (in this case), it doesn't support HTML bodies or multipart content. That means javascript itself won't help.

There are just a few options left:

- If it is a company specific system, you could integrate with [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) to create a new email with attachment
- Ask the user to download and attach the file
- *(Don't EVER do this, it is the worst idea EVER)* Use ActiveX and Outlook Automation objects to create an email and add the attachment. This will only work on IE, and most companies will block this since it uses ActiveX. *(As they should!)*

Comment: Hello Patrick,
EWS solution sounds interesting and I will try to read more on that. Any suggestions with respect to taking a screenshot as image of a specific UI element?

Comment: You can using canvas I think. Let me take a look... Found it. Take a look [here](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Comment: Actually I did come across this solution but "The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation as it does not make an actual screenshot" this was my concern...But still I will try to produce the results and test it :) Appreciate u r time!!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you may consider taking a screenshot and then uploading it to your web server for further processing and sending emails. Also you can develop a plugin for browsers where you can do whatever you need. However, the end users must install it to be able to do whatever you need.