# how do i attach a file with email using outlook application in chrome

Tags: javascript, email, outlook

I have tried email functionality with Attachment in IE with Activex Object  it is working fine but in Chrome its not Working for me.

I have searched in google but didn't get anything about chrome.

Can you help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't expose any client application behaviors such as ActiveX does within IE.

[See related SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776672/opening-outlook-through-javascript) Outlook automation in JavaScript is only supported in IE since Microsoft has provided the necessary sandboxing for security and operating system hooks.

Comment: Thanks Chris but i really need to work on this because we need this functionality to work in chrome  if you know more on this please do help me

Comment: I'm really sorry Gautam, but Chrome just doesn't support Office automation. I spent many a day ripping my hair out until this was explained to me.

Comment: thanks Chris ,@gautam did you got any workaround for that ?