How to Attach Files from a web app to Local Outlook Client?
I'm working on a task where I need to implement a button in the frontend that opens the local Outlook client to compose an email.
The user selects files (.dat or .csv) in the frontend, and upon clicking the button, Outlook should open with a default message and the selected files already attached, allowing the user to review the email before sending it.
I understand that it might be easier to send the emails directly from the application, but that’s not the desired approach for this project.
Can you please let me know if this is even possible, and if so, how I could implement it?
I’ve tried using the Outlook API, but it didn’t meet my needs because it doesn’t open Outlook before sending the email, which is a key requirement for this project.
Additionally, I cannot use links; the files must be attached directly as they are.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776672/opening-outlook-through-javascript
